# WebClient.Download returning 0 bytes

Tags: .net, webclient

I'm having a problem downloading data using WebClient.Download. It always returns 0 bytes, even though I know from FTPing in another program, or looking at WebClient.ResponseHeaders, that the file is 1731 bytes in length. This occurs using FtpWebResposne too.

The only anomalous clue is that the Encoding of the client response is set to System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding which I understand is a Western encoding, but I've never heard of it.

Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this issue?

Thanks, Mark

Comment: WebClient doesn't have a method called Download. What method are you using exactly? Could you post your code?

Comment: Uri uri = new Uri("test.csv");

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Proxy = new WebProxy(@"proxyAddress");
                client.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

                byte[] bytes;
                bytes = client.DownloadData(uri);
                string page = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(bytes);
                Console.WriteLine(page);
            }

Comment: How do you add pretty comments to this site??